# Selecting the right element with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have recently just begun using JQuery and AJAX. I am practicing using JQuery to grab form values upon form submit and using AJAX to process the data with a PHP script. It all works really good, that is, until I add another form to the page. No matter what form I submit, the data from the first form on the page gets submitted. How can I select only the form and values from the form that is being submitted?

Here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>
<title> JQUERY and AJAX </title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- JQUERY script to submit the form without page refresh !-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form").submit(function() {

        var name = $("input#name").val();

        var dataString = 'name='+ name;
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "ajax_submit.php",  
            data: dataString,                       
        }); 

        $("input#name").val("");            

        return false; 

    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form name="form" action=""/>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>

<form name="form" action=""/>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: give each form a unique id, then use that

Comment: As a tip for your feature learing: use .serialize() when you want to submit a form via ajax. It will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know how to use css selectors? You can use css selectors as jquery selectors. Meaning, if you give each form an id attribute, you can choose it later like this :

```
$('#the_forms_id').submit();
```

Where form id is an html attribute you chose for the form, like this

```
<form name="form" action="" id = "the_forms_id"/>
```

Just use php to set different form id's

Also, note you can use almost any css selector you can think of, and also jquery specific selectors. You can see them [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

If you don't know how to use basic selectors, use [this](http://learnwebcode.com/basic-css-selectors/) guide.

If you want to choose a dynamically created form (like you commented), 
implementation depends on which way the form is added and how it needs needs to be captured.
You can use php to give them different ids, dynamically (use a counter for example).

Also, you can use jquery selectors to choose the first or last element (or any other), when there are a few elements present. Check out [the :last selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) :

```
$('form :last').serialize().submit()
```

Comment: I know how to use selectors. But if the selector is dynamic, then how do I write my JQuery Selector? Thanks

Comment: edited the answer, hope this helps, also check out the link to list of jquery selectors, I am confident you will find there the one you need exactly.